# successful and fail callbacks in ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have this functions which sends a `get` request to a server. It can be called with optional params so with/out data, successful or fail callback. I call it like this:

```
get('ajax/search.php', {q: q}, function(data) {
    //success
}, function() {
    //fail
});
```

The problem is that `both callback function are being called`. I want to call only one of them. So if the request is successful `done()` will be called, or if failed `fail()` will be called

I know you can do this in jQuery but I decided to switch to pure JavaScript for speed and performance.

```
function get() {
    var data,
        done,
        fail,
        done_index = null,
        str = '',
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        url = arguments[0];

    for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
        if(typeof arguments[i] == 'object') {
            data = arguments[i];

            for(var key in data) {
                if(str != "") str += "&";

                str += key + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[key]);
            }

            if(str != '') url += '?';
        } else if(typeof arguments[i] == 'function') {
            if(done_index == null) {
                done = arguments[i];
                done_index = i;
            }

            if(i != done_index) {
                fail = arguments[i];
            }
        }
    }

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajax.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && ajax.status === 200) {
            if(done) {
                if(JSON.parse(ajax.responseText))
                    done(JSON.parse(ajax.responseText));
                else if(ajax.responseText == '')
                    done();
            }

            if(fail) fail();
        }
    };

    ajax.open('get', url + str);
    ajax.send();
}
```

Comment: Both done and fail appear to be defined when you call `get()`.   The logic of your code clearly calls both done and fail.  If you want `fail` not to be called, then you need to `return done()` instead of just `done()`.

Comment: Thanks man I thought before about it but I didn't know return will work in `asyc` calls. Thanks